# react hooks update state issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My application is storing the entire state of a "board" in the board component vie `useState`. I then map the state to create lists.

When I try to delete a list via an `axios` call, and then splice that list from my state, I am encountering an issue. The target list is not being deleted, instead the last list of the board is being deleted instead. Here is a quick screen recording of the issue: https://streamable.com/uarb97

As you can see from the alerts, everything is going as expected. I don't see why the wrong list is being spliced. here is my handleDelete function that is being passed from the board component to each list component:

```
const handleDeleteList = (targetList) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let newBoard = { ...boardState };

        alert(`DELETING ${JSON.stringify(targetList.title)} FROM INDEX ${newBoard.lists.indexOf(targetList)}`)

        newBoard.lists.splice(newBoard.lists.indexOf(targetList), 1);

        alert(`BOARD WILL NOW HAVE LISTS: ${JSON.stringify(newBoard.lists)}`)

        //setState function
        setBoardState({ ...newBoard });

        console.log("THIS IS THE CURRENT STATE THAT IS BEING MAPPED OVER TO DISPLAY THE LISTS") 
       console.log(boardState.lists)
  };
```

EDIT: I have updated the `handleDeleteList` function to use the setState function, but I am getting the same issue:

```
        updateBoardState(oldBoard => {
          const newBoard = { ...oldBoard }
          newBoard.lists.splice(oldBoard.lists.indexOf(targetList), 1)
          return newBoard
        })
```

Is this a rendering issue, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think because of this line  :  let newBoard = { ...board };  after you delete item   then  , you set old board as new board.   also remove item in board with filter

Comment: @Bahtiyar Sorry? Why would that cause the issue. I am creating a copy of the state, splicing from the copy, and then setting the state to the copy. This is to avoid direct state mutation. Am I missing something?

Comment: and there is something else. in your screen record , you want to delete id 5 , but 
instead, id 7 is deleted. Did you see ?

Comment: @Bahtiyar Yes. That is the issue. The wrong item is being deleted.

Comment: I'm out of topic, What CSS library did you use (If it is a library)? it looks great.

Comment: @HamzaKhattabi lol, I used tailwindcss. Any chance you could help ? :)

Comment: Why did you not use filter method for your list instad of splice ? (Thanks for the library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is:

```
        updateBoardState(oldBoard => {
          const newBoard = { ...oldBoard }
          newBoard.lists.splice(oldBoard.lists.indexOf(targetList), 1)
          return newBoard
        })
```

When you spread `oldBoard` you are making a shallow-copy of `lists` which means this:

```
newBoard.lists.splice(oldBoard.lists.indexOf(targetList), 1)
```

Mutates `oldBoard.lists` which causes React to get confused.

You can see this in a Code Sandbox which simulates this issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-bush-i4kew try and delete several items and you will see it getting more incorrect as it goes.

---

If you make a copy of `lists` and do your splice on that, then construct your newBoard, you won't mutate `oldBoard`:

```
updateBoardState(oldBoard => {
        const lists = oldBoard.lists.slice();
        lists.splice(oldBoard.lists.indexOf(targetList), 1);
        return { ...oldBoard, lists };
      });
```

Again, this is the same Code Sandbox with the working logic: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-mcnulty-h7378